# Compact Sets in Hausdorff Space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $K_1, K_2 \subseteq X$ be disjoint compact subsets. I wish to show that there are disjoint opens $O_1, O_2 \subseteq X$ with $K_1 \subseteq O_1, K_2 \subseteq O_2$.

There already are many answers to this question in this forum. However, I would like to prove it (if even possible) using the following fact:

> A compact Hausdorff space $Y$ is normal (i.e., $T_1$ and $T_4$).

A space is $T_4$ if any two closed disjoint subsets can be separated.

Thank you already!

Comment: Doesn't this follow directly from the fact that $Y$ is normal? As $K_1, K_2$ are compact in a Hausdorff space, they are closed, so they can be separated

Comment: Hint : In a hausdorff space a compact set and a point which is not in the compact set can be covered by two disjoint open sets.

Comment: @NicolásVilches I do not assume that $X$ is compact, so $X$ is not necessarily normal, right?

Comment: @S.G Is not this the $T_3$ property, whereas Hausdorff is the $T_2$ property?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, I know this! (However, $X$ is not compact, in case I did not highlight this enough)

Comment: I don't think you can prove this from the cited fact. The normality does not extend outside of $K_1$, $K_2$.

Answer (score -1):

The fact

> A compact Hausdorff space Y is normal (i.e., T1 and T4).

is derived from the fact that I want to prove, so I guess there is no good way show the claim the way I wanted to.